# opencl value assignment gets screwed

Tags: c, opencl

I'm trying to write an interpolation tool that works on a 3D cube, but I'm somehow not getting the values across correctly.
here is my simplified kernel that should reassign the values from one array to the other

```
__kernel void interpolate(__global float* input, __global float* output){
    output[0] = input[0];
    output[1] = input[1];
    output[2] = input[2];
    output[3] = input[3];
    output[4] = input[4];
}
```

if I now read the output array back into my CPU code I should get the values that I put into the input array back out in the exact order.
I know the above example doesn't do anything smart, but I'm interested in the principle.

the output that I should get is:

```
input0: 42.392487
input1: 20.455040
input2: 3.366035
input3: 20.000000
input4: 0.948683
```

but I get:

```
output0: 42.392487
output1: 20.455040
output2: 20.000000
output3: 20.000000
output4: 20.000000
```

any hints on where I'm going wrong here?

**UPDATE:** (again: with added input/output declaration and updated CL_MEM_READ_ONLY)

here is the code to create the memory, copy the data to the device and set the kernel args

```
float *input = malloc(sizeof(float)*counter);
float *output = malloc(sizeof(float)*counter);
input = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  sizeof(input), intput, NULL);
output = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  sizeof(output), output, NULL);
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input);
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
```

Comment: Are you passing 2 distinct buffers as kernel args, or two times the same?

Comment: I'm passing 2 distinct buffers, one after the other

Comment: The second clSetKernelArg should be with index 1. The host code you added doesn't make sense: what is the type of 'input'?

Comment: sorry - my bad copying the same line and not changing everything. the second input= is actually output= and the second kernelarg is index 1 (it's just about sunrise here ...) I've changed the WRITE_ONLY as you suggested but I get the same result

Comment: Also add your clEnqueueNDRangeKernel call.

Comment: The return value for clCreateBuffer is a cl_mem. You put it in _input_ which is a float *. How are you reading the values back?

Comment: i'm using `clEnqueueReadBuffer(commands, output, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(result), result, 0, NULL, NULL )` to read the results. I think I found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that if you declare your variable as pointer aka :

```
cl_float *input = malloc(sizeof(cl_float)*counter);
cl_float *output = malloc(sizeof(cl_float)*counter);
```

then

```
sizeof(input); // == 8
```

will return the size of a float pointer (in your case, with a 64bits system, it return 8)
instead of the size of your array.

to have the size of the array you need instead to pass the same argument than to malloc :

```
sizeof(cl_float) * counter; // == size your array
```

so you should create your buffer with the current statement :

```
input_buf = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  sizeof(cl_float) * counter, intput, NULL);
output_buf = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  sizeof(cl_float) * counter, output, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above problem was not to use

```
float *input = malloc(sizeof(float)*counter);
```

to allocate the memory, but rather do it this way:

```
float input[counter];
```

once I changed to code everything started to work. This works for me, but now I have a more complex problem, which I will list in a separate thread as it is not related to the above problem.

Thanks for all your help guys.